# get the value of dropdown select options using ajax

Tags: php, ajax

i am stuck,the select options value is sent but it sets the value to 0 all the time i execute the query. how can i get the value of the options to be grabbed ? i would be very grateful for the answer. thanks

here is the form for the select options

```
            <select name="user_role" id="#user_role">
                <option>
                </option>
                <option value="1">
                    Super Admin
                </option>
                <option value="2">
                    Team Manager
                </option>
                <option value="3">
                    Staff
                </option>
            </select>
```

the ajax function i set is

```
$(".save-update").click(function(e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        //alert("save button clicked");
                        var username = $("#username").val();
                        var email = $("#email").val();
                        var user_role = $("#user_role option:selected").val();
                        $.post("../lib/ajax/edit-user-save.php",{username:username,email:email,id:id,user_role:user_role},function(data){
                                //alert(data);
                                $(".save-update").parent().parent().addClass("table-list");
                                $(".save-update").parent().parent().replaceWith(data);
                                });

                });
```

now, the edit-user-save.php where the query is done

```
if(isset($_POST['user_role'])){
            $user_role = $_POST['user_role'];
            //echo $id;
        }

    //$query = mysql_query();
    $query = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET username='$username', email='$email',user_role='$user_role' WHERE id=$id");
    if(!$query){
            echo "could not update the table".mysql_error();
        }
```

Comment: How do you get 1 votesup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ID is not correct in HTML, change this

```
id="#user_role"
```

to this

```
id="user_role"
```

Answer (score 1):

oh i got the answer, so stupid of me

id="#user_role"

i wrote # at the id .. haha ... !

Comment: i dont know , may be beacuse i found my mistake : D

Answer (score 1):

**Replace**

```
 id="#user_role">
```

**with**

```
 id="user_role">
```