# Give a variable value from <select> dropdown

Tags: php, html, sql

Im making a function that are getting information from my SQL server.
What im trying to make it do is the following:

1. Fill a dropdown list. WORKING
2. Select from dropdown list. NO CLUE.
3. SQL query with the selected dropdown value. KIND OF KNOW
   *"Austmann" will be changed with the selected value*

   ```
   function runMyFunction() {

   $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM olsortriment WHERE bryggeri ='austmann'") 

   or die(mysql_error());  

   echo "<table border='1'>";
   echo "<tr> <th>Name</th> <th>Age</th> </tr>";

   while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
      echo "<tr><td>"; 
      echo $row['navn'];
      echo "</td><td>"; 
      echo $row['bryggeri'];
      echo "</td></tr>"; 
   } 

   echo "</table>";
   }
   if (isset($_GET['hello'])) {
      runMyFunction();
   }
   ?>
   ```

   Run PHP Function

What should i do to populate my variable with the selected item from drop-down list?

Comment: My answer here might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34812089/selecting-default-value-in-html-dropdown-list/34817939#34817939 You get the numerical value back and use that to look up what you want, so you never use what is submitted directly on your database as a query - which should nowadays be mysqli. The `onChange` event submits the page. The act of getting the submitted value as intval($_POST['dropdown_name']); forces whatever is submitted to be a number - anything else will be 0. You can then get your result from your database - if the value is 1 get this, if it is 2 get that etc.

Comment: Your dropdown list must, of course, be in a form. Here is one answer which has an HTML page of script you can put into a PHP page and play with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361452/many-elements-of-a-listbox-to-another/34367418#34367418