# How to have a value already selected from <select> tag

Tags: php, html, html-select

I have the following dropdown implemented:

```
<select style="margin-left:25px;">
     <option value="null"> </option>
     <option value="single">Single</option>
     <option value="in_a_relationship">In a relationship</option>
     <option value="engaged">Engaged</option>
     <option value="married">Married</option>
     <option value="open_rel">In an open relationship</option>
     <option value="divorced">Divorced</option>
 </select>
```

Say for example, a user has already selected `Single` from the drop down menu. When they do back to this page, I want `single` to be already chosen from the list. For text fields I can simply get the value from the database and then assign it to a variable and then echo it in the `value`. I.e.

```
$get_data2 = mysqli_query ($connect, "SELECT * FROM user_bio WHERE username = '$username'");
        $row3 = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($get_data2);
                $bio = $row3['about_me'];
```

and then do ...

```
<textarea name="biotextarea" form="change_details" rows="4" cols="60" maxlength="255"><?php echo $bio; ?> </textarea>
```

How can I do this for a `select` tag?

Comment: You could use something like this - my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34812089/selecting-default-value-in-html-dropdown-list/34817939#34817939 Giving the dropdown numerical values and "looking them up" is a safer way to use values with the database as submitted values and the database never come into direct contact. This also has other ideas for select dropdowns which you might find useful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361452/many-elements-of-a-listbox-to-another/34367418#34367418

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to select the option `Single` in HTML :

```html
<select style="margin-left:25px;">
     <option value="null"> </option>
     <option value="single" selected>Single</option>
     <option value="in_a_relationship">In a relationship</option>
     <option value="engaged">Engaged</option>
     <option value="married">Married</option>
     <option value="open_rel">In an open relationship</option>
     <option value="divorced">Divorced</option>
 </select>
```

So, how to set this in PHP?!

Well, you could generate your `<select>` element like this :

```
<?php
$options = [
    'null' => ' ',
    'single' => Single',
    'in_a_relationship' => 'In a relationship',
    'engaged' => 'Engaged',
    'married' => 'Married',
    'open_rel' => 'In an open relationship',
    'divorced' => 'Divorced'
];
?>
<select style="margin-left:25px;"><?php
     foreach($options as $key => $value) {
          echo '<option value="' . $key . '"';
          if ($key === $row3['status']){
              echo ' selected';
          }
          echo '>' . $value . '</option>';
     }
?></select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting a preselected option on a select tag requires you to put a selected attribute on the selected option.

```
<select style="margin-left:25px;">
<?php
   $options = array(array("null"," "),array("single","Single"),array("in_a_relationship","In a relationship"),array("engaged","Engaged"),array("married","Married"),array("open_rel","In an open relationship"),array("divorced","Divorced"));
   foreach ($option in $options){
       if ($option[0] == $row3['status']){
           $selected = 'selected ';
       }
       else{
           $selected = '';
       }
       echo '<option '.$selected.'value="'.htmlspecialchars($option[0]).'">'.htmlspecialchars($option[1]).'</option>';
   } 
?>
 </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution of Musa it's OK, but If you don't want to change your PHP too much 
you can do the task with Javascript.

With jQuery or pure Javascript

```
function selector(id, value){
    select = document.getElementById(id);
  for(i=0;i<select.options.length;i++){
    if(select.options[i].value == value){
        select.selectedIndex = i;
    }
  }

}
//Pure Javascript
selector("status", "engaged")

//With jQuery
jQuery('#status').val('married');
```

Check this [Snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/maflorezp/02voLbpy/)